# Docker apache2 will not consider new 000-default.conf

Tags: php, apache, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile

I am trying to dockerize Laravel 5.2 app. For this I am using following images,

```
php:apache
mysql:5.7
```

Below is my `docker-compose.yml`

```
web:
  build: .
  volumes:
    - ./:/var/www/html
  ports:
    - "9899:80"
  links:
    - db
  command : [/usr/sbin/apache2ctl, -D, FOREGROUND]

db:
  image: mysql:5.7
  volumes:
    - /home/data:/var/lib/mysql
  environment:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: custom
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: custom
```

And my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM php:apache
RUN apt-get update && docker-php-ext-install pdo pdo_mysql
RUN rm -f /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
ADD ./settings/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available
```

Both `Dockerfile` and `docker-compose.yml` are in the `laravel` root directory. To run laravel based app, server must point to `public` folder. So, you can see I am replacing `apache2`'s default configuration file with below `000-default.conf` file,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```

Everything runs fine on `docker-compose up` command but, when I browse `localhost:9899` I get Forbidden error, but `localhost:9899/public` launches `laravel` app correctly. That means my supplied `000-default.conf` is not having effect and server still points to `/var/www/html/` instead of `/var/www/html/public`.

So I tried, `exec` to get into running container to check the `000-default.conf`. And I could see my file instead of default.  I am not getting my head around this issue. I want apache to consider my `000-default.conf` . I hope you guys can see what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 6):

Apache does not look into the `sites-available` directory but rather in the `sites-enabled` directory.
You can either `ADD` your config-file into the latter directory, or set up a symlink:

```
ADD ./settings/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available
RUN ln -s /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

Comment: Configuration File in sites-enabled is a symlink that points to file in sites-available

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the docker container for php:8.2-apache in 2023 contains an included symlink for :

```
/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf -> ../sites-available/000-default.conf
```

I was so confused after reading this article, because I realized I was editing the the sites-available conf file, which is the correct file, thanks to that symlink.

To compare then to now, my dockerfile looks like so:

```
FROM php:8.2-apache

COPY ./000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
```

Or instead in a docker-compose.yaml it would be

```
services:
  web:
    image: php:8.2-apache
    volumes:
      - ./000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf
```

And finally my public directory was specified in that conf file like so:

```
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/public
    DirectoryIndex index.php
```